# marklogic corb run is generating one file for each uri

Tags: xquery, marklogic-10, marklogic-corb

I am trying extract report from Marklogic but for each uri I am getting one document.

```
java -cp marklogic-xcc-10.0.10.jar:marklogic-corb-2.5.6.jar -DXCC-CONNECTION-URI=xcc://user:pw@host:5008 -DPROCESS-MODULE=/corb/transform-docs.xqy -DTHREAD-COUNT=2 -DURIS-MODULE=/corb/get-uris.xqy -DPROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask -DEXPORT-FILE-NAME=/reports/testfile.csv com.marklogic.developer.corb.Manager
```

MarkLogic version - 10.x

In the process module I am just returning string value.

I want to generate one output file only, which should have all of the returned uris.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write all of the output to a single doc, then you should use the `ExportBatchToFileTask` instead of `ExportToFileTask`.

The description listed in the [PROCESS-TASK](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2#PROCESS-TASK)

> - `com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask` Generates a ***single file***, typically used for reports. Writes the data returned by the **PROCESS-MODULE** to a single file specified by **EXPORT-FILE-NAME**. All returned values from entire CoRB will be streamed into the single file.
> - `com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportToFileTask` Generates ***multiple files***. Saves the documents returned by each invocation of **PROCESS-MODULE** to a separate local file within **EXPORT-FILE-DIR** where the file name for each document will be the based on the URI.

So, configure the *ExportBatchToFileTask*:

```
PROCESS-TASK=com.marklogic.developer.corb.ExportBatchToFileTask
```

instead of *ExportToFileTask*.